# ExtJs: Tree: how to scroll directly to a specific element?

Tags: javascript, tree, extjs

I'm looking for a way to scroll to a specific element in a Tree.
Any idea how to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had to call `n.select();` but I had to do it in the right place :)

I made a TreeLoader, and linked it to my tree. In its event `load` (which means 'when all is downloaded', I would have called it `afterload`...), I read all the nodes and depending on their `id` I act consequently:

```
var LasTreeLoader = new Ext.tree.TreeLoader({
    dataUrl: 'json/las.php',
    listeners: {
        load: function(loader,n,response) {
        console.log('datas downloaded');
        n.eachChild(
            function(n) {
                if ((n.id=='las/2007') ||
                    (n.id=='las/2007/08') ||
                    (n.id=='las/2007/08/29')) {
                    n.expand(false,false);
                }
                if (n.id=='las/2007/08/29/21_14_04') {
                    n.select();
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your node click event handler:

```
node.getUI().getIconEl().scrollIntoView(node.getOwnerTree(), false);
```

Comment: Hi ! I've not tried it, but it may work. See my answer to see what I've done :)

Answer (score 1):

The DOM `scrollIntoView` doesn't really work as expected as it always either top or bottom aligns the element. ExtJS however seems to have just what is needed:

```
Ext.get(el|elId).scrollIntoView(containerId|containerEl);
```

For example, to ensure the currently selected item in an `Ext.view.View` (dataview) instance is visible, I did:

```
Ext.define('MyView', {
    extend: 'Ext.view.View',
    ...

    listeners: {
        'selectionchange': function(_, selections) {
            if (selections.length === 1) {
                var node = this.getNode(selections[0]);
                Ext.fly(node).scrollIntoView(this.el);
            }
        }
    },
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't directly related to extJs, but you could get the DOM element you want in your tree and use [`scrollTo`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/DOM/window.scrollTo) to get to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var path = tree.getSelectionModel().getSelectedNode().getPath('id');  
    //reload data,  
    tree.getLoader().load(tree.getRootNode(),function(treeNode){  
    //expand path and select node
    tree.expandPath(path,'id',function(bSucess,oLastNode){  
        tree.getSelectionModel().select(oLastNode);  
    });  
},this);
```