# Expanding extjs tree to see one element

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I can add element to tree in extjs and I want to see it just after adding. How can I focus on than element (expand everything before it and put selection on it)?

Comment: Any news? I'm curious to know if you managed to do what you wanted

Comment: Yes, everything works pretty good, thanks a lot

Comment: Can you mark this question as resolved then please? ;) (Sorry for begging). Giving feedbacks about your success or failure will help the next readers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the method `selectPath` on your `TreePanel` as detailed here:

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.tree.Panel-method-selectPath

This method will open every nodes needed to access your element and select this element. The way you express the path is as follow:

```
Ext.getCmp('treePanel').selectPath('/Root/Leaf/Element', 'text')
```

Here, the `text` property of my `TreeModel` has been used (The second parameter), but you can change that for anything, like the `id`.

```
Ext.getCmp('treePanel').selectPath('/1/16/42', 'id')
```

To build this `path`, the better way is to use the method `getPath` on the particular item you want to select:

```
item.getPath('text')
```

Comment: I noticed that even though tree is expanded and proper element selected, I have to scroll down to see that selected element. How can I scroll automatically?

Comment: This has more to do with general panels that specifically the Tree. But there is an interesting thread about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036775/extjs-tree-how-to-scroll-directly-to-a-specific-element They seems to manage doing what you want.