# Extjs Scroll to position inside tabPanel

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, extjs4

I have a window, containing a tabPanel, this tabPanel has 4 tabs.
I wanted to write down something like user manual so I created several panels as blocks, each panel contains some text and pics.

from another button, I want to scroll to a particular postiton in that tab. How can I do it? here is my structure, and let's say I want the button to open the first tab, scrolling to the third panel (id:here).

tabPanel:

```
 var   tabs = Ext.createWidget('tabpanel', {
       id: 'myTabs',
        header: false,
        activeTab: 3,
    closable: true,
    defaults:{ autoScroll:true },       
        items: [

        {
            title: 'first',
            itemId: 'firstTab',         
            items: [
            {
                xtype: 'panel',
                html: text39,
                cls: 'layout_text1'
            },
           {        
            xtype: 'panel',
               html: text40,
            cls:'layout_subtitle'
            },{
                xtype: 'panel',
                id: 'here',
                html: text41,
                cls: 'layout_text2'
            }]  
});
```

window:

```
var UMwindow = new Ext.Window({
            id: 'myWindow',
        name: 'userManual',
            closable: true,
            floating: true,
            width: 900,
            height: 600,
        items  : myTabs,


}).show();
```

I managed to open the window then activating the first tab using: `Ext.getCmp('tabs').setActiveTab('firstTab');` but then I couldn't figure out how to scroll down to the position i need "third panel in my example". do I have to add property to the panel such as position or something?

Comment: Please reformat/complete the tabPanel code, the last two lines are confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I would gladly help but I'm unable to get a working jsfiddle demo out of this. I imagine that what you are trying to do requires firing `setActiveTab` for the tab panel then jumping  to the item you would like to show, using that item's [offset](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?238420-Scroll-to-view-the-selected-list-item-function).

Comment: Thanks. I managed to open the window then activating the first tab using:  `Ext.getCmp('tabs').setActiveTab('firstTab');` but then I couldn't figure out how to scroll down to the position i need "third panel in my example". do I have to add property to the panel such as position or something?

Comment: Did you check the forum link? http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?238420-Scroll-to-view-the-selected-list-item-function
You have the id set, so you can try getting the element using `Ext.get('here')` and scroll to its offset.

Comment: Check this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036775/extjs-tree-how-to-scroll-directly-to-a-specific-element